# manipulação de string python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estou tendo um problema em relação do \b do python (backspace), ao invés dele apagar o carácter anterior, ele gera um "•" conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a linha do código que gera esse retorno:

```
     #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import platform
import json
#------------------------------------------------------#
local_arq = open("C:\Zabbix\prm2.txt", 'r') #Caminho do arquivo cujo encontra-se aa instancias
leitura = local_arq.readlines() #leitura das linhas do arquivo
varhost = platform.node()
x = 0 #var usada para separar os dados recebidos do TXT && Alterar o valor do hostname 
y = 0 
with open("test3.txt","w") as arq:
    print('{"data": [')
    for li in leitura:
        count = li.split('--') #count = contador ele recebe os dados do TXT e separa eles onde tem o -
        count[x].replace(" ", "") #Remove todos os espaços

        for li2 in count:   
            hostname = varhost + '\\' + count[x]
            con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server="+hostname+";uid=sa;pwd=Ww1234567.")
            query = con.cursor()
            query.execute("SELECT name FROM SYSDATABASES")

            for row in query:    
                #print(row)
                print('{"{#INSTANCENAME}": "%s","{#DBNAME}": "%s"},' %(count[x], row[y]))
                lol = ('{"{#INSTANCENAME}": "%s","{#DBNAME}": "%s"},' %(count[x], row[y]))
            x = x + 1
            print(lol + '\b]}')
        y = y + 1
```

No caso, estou usando o \b para apagar aquela virgula.

Desde já grato!

OBS: Versão do Python 3.7

Comment: Na verdade este aí é o caractere gráfico equivalente ao código ASCII 8, veja aqui: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Codepage-437.png Pelo visto você está salvando o arquivo em disco e não exibindo-o na tela, logo é mais prático você cortar este caractere antes da impressão ao invés de tentar "cortá-lo" dentro do arquivo.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Voc}e está sujeito a erros escabrosos já na linha `open("C:\Zabbix\prm2.txt", 'r')` - justamente por que a  `\ ` é prefixo de escape para alguns caracteres especiais - use ou "/" pra frente - é compatível mesmo no Windows, ou uma string com prefixo "r" :  `open(r"C:\Zabbix\prm2.txt", 'r')`

Answer (score 3):

Há um erro de conceito aí - o "\b" é simplesmente um carácter de controle, de nome "backspace", que tem código decimal "8" - quando impresso num *terminal , o protocolo do terminal é que faz com que o caractere anterior seja apagado*.

Mas para gravação num arquivo, o "\b" é um caractére como outro qualquer - na maior parte das codificações de texto - ASCII, Latin1 e UTF-8 inclusive, simplesmente vai gerar um byte com valor "8" que vai ficar no arquivo. E aí, se o arquivo for impresso, num terminal, vai parecer que o caractere anterior foi apagado - tente aí, em vez de abrir seu arquivo num editor de textos, exibir seu conteúdo (comando `cat` no Linux/Unix/OS X, ou `type` no DOS/windows).

Ou seja, o que você precisa fazer é não gravar a vírgula indesejada no arquivo para começar. 
VOcê não colocou mais partes do seu programa, então não dá pra dizer exatamente nde você pode fazer isso, mas em geral vai exigir que você tenha uma vairável de "contador", e grave a vírgula no começo de cada item, se aquele item *não*  for o primeiro.

Ou, se você tiver toda a lista de itens quando for fazer a gravação, o método `.join` das listas em Python já coloca as vírgulas apenas como separadores dos itens. Então, vamos supor que você tenha tudo o que quer gravar no arquivo numa lista "valores", pode fazer assim:

```
arq.write("""{"chave":[%s]}""" % ", ".join(valores))
```

(Aqui usei o modo antigo `%` para interpolar strings para evitar ter que escapar as chaves do dicionário de fora, usando `.format` ou f-strings)

Uma alternativa melhor ainda, se você está criando um arquivo JSON é deixar o Python transformar  uma estrutura de dados "viva",  composta de diionários e listas na string JSON.

```
import json
arq.write(json.dumps(meus_dados))
```

onde "meus_dados" é um dicionário, com as listas e sub-dicionários necessários. 
Usar o JSON encoder é muito melhor do que tentar gerar a string manualmente, por que ele dá conta de todos os outros casos em que o JSON daria erro, como aspas dentro das strings, números muito grandes, valores "None" do Python, etc...

## Em resumo:

- Uso o `json.dumps` para criar sua string JSON - não tente
  codifica-la manualmente.
- O "\b" não funciona mesmo por que ele na
  verdade imprime um caractere **a mais**. O protocolo dos terminais é
  que usa esse caractere como código de controle para voltar uma
  posição.

Comment: Caraa primeiramente muito obrigado pela ajuda sua explicação me deu uma Luz!

E eu compliquei muito sem o código peço perdão, já editei e coloquei todo o meu código fonte para melhor exemplificar minha duvida,

Comment: Sobre o uso do import json eu tentei porém tem algumas mudanças na versão JSON para a versão JSON RPC 2

Comment: Eu acho bem pouco provável que o json _consumido_ pelo protocolo específico não seja JSON válido - ele pode ser um sub-conjunto de Json válido.  Ademais, o módulo json do Python tem bastante flexibilidade para personalizar a serialização - eu duvido muito que não tenha como usa-lo. Eu recomendaria você tentar usar o json do Python, e se tiver erro, criar outra pergunta incluindo os erros específicos. (deixe essa como está - esclarecemos o "\b" aqui)

Comment: Ok irei fazer isso, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre a serialização e caso encontre problema crio uma nova pergunta Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Há duas sugestões para você usar, a primeira é salvar direto no arquivo sem a "," o que facilitaria as coisas. Caso não seja possível, a segunda é fazer uma "copia" de cada linha e simplesmente cortar o "," delas, dessa forma:

```
with open('dbname.txt', 'r+') as Arq:
    for line in Arq:
        # .split() corta a linha do arquivo exatamente no caracter ',' e forma uma lista,
        # que no seu caso tem duas partes, antes e após a virgula.
        novalinha = line.split(',')
        # Refaz tudo em outro arquivo, de maneira correta.
        with open('tmp.txt', 'w+') as NewArq:
            NewArq.write(novalinha[0] + novalinha[1])
```

Assim cada linha seria a mesma, com a diferença de que você eliminaria o "," delas, depois é só passar todas as linhas para o arquivo original novamente.

Comment: A sua sugestão foi perfeita porém, o arquivo é um JSON RPC 2, tem que existir a virgula em cada linha, somente na ultima linha que não possui, segue um exemplo do que estou fazendo:

esse é o código:

{
    "data": [
        {
            "{#HOST}": "Japan 1",
            "{#COUNT}": "5"
        },
        {
            "{#HOST}": "Japan 2",
            "{#COUNT}": "12"
        },
        {
            "{#HOST}": "Latvia",
            "{#COUNT}": "3"
        }
    ]
}

perceba que na ultima linha dos dados não possui a virgula, e no validador de JSON d erro com a ultima ",

Comment: Eu não conheço nem manipulo esse tipo de arquivo JSON, mas você não poderia ajeita-los em txt para só depois transforma-los no JSON? Talvez ajudasse facilitando o processo, ou talvez tenha um método mais simples manipulando o proprio arquivo o qual eu não saiba.

Comment: Já consegui, eu fiz da seguinte maneira: Localizo a ultima linha, apago ela e fora do for printo a ultima linha sem a virgula no caso